# How to store test data creation scripts in maven?

Tags: maven, selenium

I have a maven project which has selenium tests for an application. The test suite has grown in terms of the features and therefore, our selenium tests need the test environments to have test data. We have created a set of test scripts that seed the data. These scripts are actually selenium scripts.
Currently, these scripts are stored in the test suite folder but I realize that might not be ideal since these are not really tests. 
Is there a better way/place to maintain these scripts in a Maven project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Ideal setup would be to have your framework, and core functions as it's own project.  Have `src/main/java` be the source folder for the framework, and `src/test/java` be the unit tests for the framework.

The other project would be the regression project.  You'd put your tests under a relevant package in `src/main/java` and have the test DATA in `src/main/resources`